# How to write a request in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

There is a list of types of documents

```
    {
    'number': '7800000000000',
    'name': 'User #',
    'sessions': [
        {
            'created_at': ISODate('2016-01-01T00:00:00'),
            'session_id': '6QBnQhFGgDgC2FDfGwbgEaLbPMMBofPFVrVh9Pn2quooAcgxZc',
            'actions': [
                {
                    'type': 'read',
                    'created_at': ISODate('2016-01-01T01:20:01'),
                },
                {
                    'type': 'read',
                    'created_at': ISODate('2016-01-01T01:21:13'),
                },
                {
                    'type': 'create',
                    'created_at': ISODate('2016-01-01T01:33:59'),
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

It is necessary to write an aggregation request, which for each user will display the last action
and the total for each type of 'actions'. The totals should be
list of documents:

```
{
    'number': '7800000000000',
    'actions': [
        {
            'type': 'create',
            'last': 'created_at': ISODate('2016-01-01T01:33:59'),
            'count': 12,
        },
        {
            'type': 'read',
            'last': 'created_at': ISODate('2016-01-01T01:21:13'),
            'count': 12,
        },
        {
            'type': 'update',
            'last': null,
            'count': 0,
        },
        {
            'type': 'delete',
            'last': null,
            'count': 0,
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: In this case you have to aggregate because you want to group, sort and project the documents.

Comment: Yes, but so far I did not get to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$sessions"},
    {"$unwind": "$sessions.actions"},
    {"$group": {
        "_id": {
        "name": "$name", "action": "$sessions.actions.type"},
        "created_at": {"$push": "$sessions.actions.created_at"},
        "count": {"$sum": 1}
    }},
    {"$group": {
        "_id": {"name": "$_id.name"},
        "actions": {
            "$push": {
                "type": "$_id.action",
                "last": {"$max": "$created_at"},
                "count": "$count"
            }
        }
    }}
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Great job in finding your own answer!